# Multiple rounded layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Any idea how to create a control like this one?

Basically there's 5 different rounded elements (two green views, one yellow text view at top, one blue text view at bottom, and image view in the middle).

[image]

Comment: use canvas and rotate text to particular angle

Comment: Hi @HarshDevChandel I'm not very familiar with canvas, can you please help me with some sample?

Comment: you should read about how to draw text on canvas